# sqlite3.OperationalError using FLASK

Tags: flask

I have been getting errors for trying to
insert a new user on my website using flask with

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
# def register():
#     """
#     Handle creation of accounts
#     """
#     registerForm = Register()
#     if request.method == "POST":
#         try:
#             if not registerForm.validate_on_submit():
#                 abort(400)
#             email = registerForm.email.data
#             password_hash = generate_password_hash(registerForm.password.data)
#             new_user = User(
#                 email=email, password_hash=password_hash, created=dt.utcnow()
#             )
#             add_user(new_user)
#             flash(f"Account Registered. Please Log In.", "success")
#             return redirect(url_for("login"))
#         except BadRequest:
#             flash("Failed to register account.", "danger")

#     return render_template(
#         "register.html", form=registerForm, title="Rentier | Sign Up"
#     )
def register():
    """
    Handle creation of accounts
    """
    registerForm = Register()
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            print("Before validate_on_submit")
            if not registerForm.validate_on_submit():
                print("Validation failed")
                abort(400)

            email = registerForm.email.data
            password_hash = generate_password_hash(registerForm.password.data)
            #password_hash = registerForm.password.data
            new_user = User(
                email=email, password_hash=password_hash, created=dt.utcnow()
            )
            add_user(new_user)  # Assuming add_user is defined somewhere in your code

            flash(f"Account Registered. Please Log In.", "success")
            return redirect(url_for("login"))
        except BadRequest as e:
            print(f"Bad request during registration: {str(e)}")
            flash("Invalid request. Please check your input.", "danger")
        except IntegrityError as e:
            print(f"Integrity error during registration: {str(e)}")
            flash("Email address already in use. Please choose a different one.", "danger")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Unexpected error during registration: {str(e)}")
            flash("Failed to register account. Please try again later.", "danger")

    print("Rendering template")
    return render_template(
        "register.html", form=registerForm, title="Rentier | Sign Up"
    )
```

predefiend class:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    # Primary Key
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    # Email
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)

    # Password Hash
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)

    # Created
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)

    history = db.relationship("Entry", backref="user", lazy=True)

class Register(FlaskForm):
    email = EmailField("Email address", validators=[InputRequired(), Email()])

    password = PasswordField(
        "Password", validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=8), password_validator, EqualTo("confirm", "Passwords must match")]
    )

    confirm = PasswordField("Confirm password")

    submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

but im getting

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 13:02:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 13:02:27] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 13:02:27] "GET /static/images/20945765.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 13:02:27] "GET /static/images/Wavy_Tech-20_Single-08.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 13:02:28] "GET /static/images/icon.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
Rendering template
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 13:02:29] "GET /register HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 13:02:29] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 13:02:30] "GET /static/images/icon.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
Before validate_on_submit
Unexpected error during registration: 500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
Rendering template
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 13:02:48] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 13:02:48] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Dec/2023 13:02:48] "GET /static/images/icon.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

and on the website it says

```
(sqlite3.OperationalError) database is locked [SQL: INSERT INTO users (email, password_hash, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?)] [parameters: ('Mike.Hillyer@sakilastaff.com', 'scrypt:32768:8:1$CxLJCTgT594vzwoA$88fe4f4d1369d0744ac1c50dc25c1233a8155d891f1ac6140667cccd270f8051a9e4b80d8908c756cde55fbeec34f5bd7036d3800e21a47b04d0a26e7a5c3de8', '2023-12-02 05:02:43.135299')] (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

Why am i not permitted to create a new user?

Additional validation:Not sure if it affects

```
# @validates("email")
# def validate_email(self, key, email):
#     """
#     Validate email address. Email address should already have been validated by the Flask Form, but we double check the input here just in case
#     """
#     assert len(email) <= 255, "Email address should be at most 255 characters long."
#     assert (
#         re.search(r"^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$", email) is not None
#     ), "Email address is invalid"
#     return email

# @validates("password_hash")
# def validate_hash(self, key, password_hash):
#     assert (
#         len(password_hash) >= 64
#     ), "Password hash should be at least 64 characters long."
#     return password_hash

# @validates("created")
# def validates_created(self, key, created):
#     assert type(created) is dt.datetime, "created should be a datetime object"
#     return created
```

I do not think password_hash is the one resulting in this error, so im lost as to why i cant solve this error. My user table is already managed to be created in the database.